# Identity 2.0 and how to obtain comma-separated list of email addresses from List of Users

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm needing to retrieve the Username (an email address) from a list of users that are in a particular Role. I can get that list of users like this:

```
var roleManager = 
    new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new UserDbContext()));

var users = roleManager.FindByName("Administrator").Users.ToList();

foreach (var u in users)
{
    ApplicationUser adminuser = UserManager.FindById(u.UserId);
    var emailaddress = adminuser.UserName;
}
```

What is the cleanest way to iterate through this list of `users` to create a string of comma separated usernames? My thinking is that this is probably able to be done all within the second line of code above? The format I'm looking for is:

```
"email1@domain.com, email2@domain.com, ..."
```

Comment: [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Tim, thanks for the pointer. Maybe should have elaborated a little more. The Username isn't available in the list of `users` so I needed to make another call. Is it possible to make that call differently so that the username is returned in the result?

Comment: StringBuilder is usually quicker when adding additional data to a string.

Comment: StringBuilder is convenient. I've just seen involved discussions here on SO that weren't in favor of it. This routine isn't an intensive part of my app though. It probably is a good choice. I like the String.Join suggestion too except that the data I need isn't in the results from the second line of my code. Seems like I need the `foreach` anyway, so `StringBuilder` is probably a good approach.